# average of derived attributes in new table

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

How can I calculate the average of a person (in this case player) x & y position whilst creating a new table and adding said average to a new column.

```
CREATE TABLE PlayerStatistics  AS SELECT
    PLAY_Name
FROM
    player;

ALTER TABLE
    PlayerStatistics ADD AveragePosition DECIMAL(6, 5)
SELECT
    AVG(
         Player1(T1) - X,
         Player1(T1) - Y
    ))
FROM
    tracksdataview
```

The end result of the code is a new table with one column of the player's name/id and another column that has an average value of both the x and y positions in each row.

Comment: How do you want to calculate the "average"? Are there more than one records for each player? Do you want the average over several records of the same player? And do you really want to combine `X` and `Y` values into a common average, or rather two separate values? If `X` and `Y` are cartesian coordinates then calculating an "average" between two dimensions does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: Is it MySQL DB?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DBMS, you may be able to combine your calculation and `CREATE TABLE` statement.

```sql
CREATE TABLE PlayerStatistics AS
SELECT 
  PLAY_Name, 
  CAST((Player_X + Player_Y) / 2 AS DECIMAL(6,5)) AS AveragePosition
FROM player p
LEFT JOIN tracksdataview tdv ON p.play_name = tdv.play_name -- Get track data (if any)
;
```

You may need to `CAST` the `x, y` values as `FLOAT` before doing the division.  Give it a try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, that a new table might not be the best solution to your problem. Consider the case where a position `X` or `Y` changes over time. This will then not be reflected in your "derived" attributes in the separate table.

My suggestion would be to generate a view that will always "look" at the original table:

```
CREATE VIEW PlayerStatistics  AS 
SELECT *, ax-X devX, ay-Y devY
FROM tracksdataview t
INNER JOIN (SELECT playerId, AVG(X) ax, AVG(Y) ay FROM tracksdataview GROUP BY playerId) ta
ON ta.playerId=t.playerId
```

As I was uncertain about the type of "average" you want I calculated an average over all positions of a particular player and then created two columns showing the player's x- and y- deviations from their average positions.

(I also made the assumption that an ID-columns (`playerId`) exists ...)